# Android - How to refresh the menu item of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Well first of all most of the code is from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

Ok, so there's a code for activity that creates a Navigation Drawer, 
The Navigation Drawer menu item includes a imageview a text and a number counter.

Now the thing I'm trying to understand is how can I make the number counter get changed acoording to data from the db.

So here's the code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    dbHand = new DbHandler(this);
    int numOfBotn = dbHand.queryAllBotnstonum();
    String numBotn = String.valueOf(numOfBotn);

    int numOfgROUPmSG = dbHand.newAllNewGroupMessages();
    String numNewgRmsg = String.valueOf(numOfgROUPmSG);

    lhand = new LocalStorageHandler(this);
    int newprasoMsg = lhand.gotAllNewMsg();
    String numNewPersonalMsg = String.valueOf(newprasoMsg);
    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), true, numNewPersonalMsg));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true , numNewgRmsg));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, numBotn));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.button_positive_off));

    //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            Log.d("OUT", "CLOSED");
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
```

Now how can i set again the `adapter` for the `mDrawerList`.

I understand that `onDrawerOpened` can be a good place to do it.

What kind of code am I need to use in order to that?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

`Now how can i set again the adapter for the mDrawerList.`

You should not. Instead, you could simply call `Adapter:notifyDatasetChanged()` if adapter's data has changed

`I understand that onDrawerOpened can be a good place to do it.`

Not sure, as it represents a Drawer in a settled state, that is - visible to user. Any changes happening from this moment on would seem strange or potentially slow down user experience, or both. I guess, though, that for the sake of simplicity *you could try it*.

A better solution would require you to implement your own [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) and a content observer that would trigger events according to changes made to your underlying datasource. And that is a bit of a challenge, if you are not familiar with these constructs yet.

`What kind of code am I need to use in order to that?`

If you intend to update your navdrawer with info from database, it would be nice if your *NavDrawerListAdapter* **would subclass** [*CursorAdapter*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

If you manage to successfully change your adapter code to work with `Cursor` instead of/in addition to hard-coded elements, the rest of your task is just as simple as:

1. Query your database for info. The result will be a [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) pointing to your data
2. Set the new Cursor to your *NavDrawerListAdapter* and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on this adapter

Again, it would be better if this *"loading"* part would happen asynchronously, in an AsyncTaskLoader, for instance, or in AsyncTask (less preferable if you do not properly handle configuration changes).